# django janja compare database value

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I have some data store in the database In boolean. I want to check if the value is True pick the value and perform some action on it.

```
product: "{{DB_report_query.product.name}}"
{% if DB_report_query.product.summary  == True %}
{{DB_report_query.summary}}
{% endif %}
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a `BooleanField` then simply use the following:

```html
{% if DB_report_query.product.summary %}
    {{DB_report_query.summary}}
{% endif %}
```